# What dictates the range of EM radiation which can be produced by semi-conductor excitation (like LEDs)

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, semiconductor-physics

Exciting semiconductors such as silicon carbide and gallium nitride can cause electroluminescence. I believe that by altering the chemistry of the semiconductor, you can alter the wavelength of the radiation emitted? I know that Infra-red LEDs exist and some UV, is there any other non-visible waves which can be emitted and is there a theoretical limit to the wavelength of EM-radiation tht can be produced with this approach?

Comment: To first order, you need to alter the band gap of the semiconductor, which means a different material. So, for example, you can grow AlGaAs anywhere from pure GaAs to pure AlAs, and each composition will have a different band gap so you can tune the wavelength. Or, you move to a different material system (InP say).  But, in general, you are stuck with 'easily' growable, direct band gap semiconductor systems. Note also that circuits can easily be built from dc to microwaves without needing electroluminescence.

Comment: With semiconductors we are, as Jon Custer said, pretty much stuck around the visible (which is a wonderful gift of physics, by the way!). Meta-materials can probably extend this somewhat towards the longer end of the spectrum, however, the bandgap energy and kT are competing for the population of these states, so the smaller the bandgap gets, the lowder we have to make the temperatures. You can see this with optical detectors for the far IR, which require Peltier coolers or even liquid nitrogen/helium cooling to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pair of bounds:

At the lower energy range, $kT$ is a limiting factor since thermal effects will swamp attempts to invert the electron/hole population.  At room temperature $kT$ is in the infra-red at about 0.025 $eV$.

At the upper energy range you need a conduction band state which is still bound to the crystal.  Among atoms, Helium has the highest ionization energy at about 27 $eV$, which is in the high energy ultraviolet.  That is likely the limit for ionizing any solid.

Thus, semiconductor LED style emission is limited to the IR, the visible, and the UV at room temperature.

I should add that it is not a coincidence that the effect is limited to the visible and to the neighboring energies which are named after "red" and "violet".  When physicists started to classify EM radiation those wavelengths that were associated with molecular transitions but were not visible to the eye were named infrared and ultraviolet.  EM radiation bands not produced by these mechanisms were given different names.